# How is this question a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

This is the question in question *[Wrong result of populating an Android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067456/wrong-result-of-populating-an-android-listview/41067646)*.

The question was asking about the Android listview adapter, and the question was marked as a duplicate of *[How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)*.

The relationship between the two questions is tangential at best. All they have in common is the `toString` method, asides from that nothing else is similar. So why was it marked as a duplicate?

Comment: If you read both questions, you will see that the problem is fundamentally the same: some part of the code calling `.toString()`. (disclaimer, I know nothing of android/java, so this is just an educated guess at most)

Comment: @Braiam I read the question

Comment: @olumide and the answer to the dupe target can't be used to answer the dupe? From a cursory glance... It seems like yes. It would of course need to be adapted to the specific problem... But the logic is there... No?

Comment: If there really is no significant connection between the two questions, can you clarify why?

Answer (score 16):

I'm the one who triggered the duplicate target.

It is your own answer that indicated that a `toString` method was necessary, so thank you for your sharing your knowledge, or rather copying your interpretation of the documentation. Stack Overflow, however, receives similar questions daily, even hourly, and it gets tiresome to provide the same answer repeatedly.

We do wish people would debug their code or would read the existing documentation for the referenced classes. Maybe even follow a proper tutorial / course to learn how the internals of the system work. But, everyone learns at their own pace, and that is wishful thinking.

Regarding your statements,

> asides from [the `toString` method] nothing else is similar

Firstly, I'm honestly not sure what you are making a big deal about this for. I'd understand if you were the person asking the question, and maybe you felt it was wrongfully closed, but you got your answer in, and the poster commented saying providing the `toString` method to the object worked. You could have asked the poster to accept your answer and moved on.

Secondly, Android is Java, and that's the common denominator in the problem. The poster was trying to display the list of user-defined Java objects, and was simply unaware of the specifics of the `ArrayAdapter`, which you were kind enough to reference the documentation (with a link to site your source). Now - I'll agree that there's probably a better Android-specific duplicate, but for those of us who hang around android / java tags, the problem is *similar enough*.

Third, notice that the question was closed by 5 different users, each of whom have their own judgment on the matter.

I hope this addresses your concerns, and doesn't dissuade you from continuing to share your knowledge with the community or reach out for any assistance of your own.

Comment: Dang. Called out on Meta, left a well-reasoned and extremely polite answer defending your decision. This is the way to do it. Rock on!

Comment: "Called out" seems strong, but in a way, sure. First answer here too, so I was worried about answering with the heavy downvotes on the question

Comment: Downvotes work a bit differently on Meta. They often signify agreement or disagreement, rather than technical correctness. People roundly disagreed with the questioning of this being a duplicate, which actually made it *safer* for you to respond. :-)